# Calling an external JQuery function from a div using it's ID

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to call an external jquery file that references a click function on a div ID. The function works great when embedded in the html page, however I want all my js to be called externally.

Here is the external js files in my head tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popuptabs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

JQuery code in for popuptabs.js

```
    jQuery(function($) {

        var open = false;

        $('#footerSlideButton').click(function () {

            if(open === false) {

                $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '300px' });

                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');

                open = true;

            } else {

                $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });

                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');

                open = false;

            }

        });     

    });


        jQuery(function($) {

        var open = false;

        $('#footerSlideButton2').click(function () {

            if(open === false) {

                $('#footerSlideContent2').animate({ height: '300px' });

                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');

                open = true;

            } else {

                $('#footerSlideContent2').animate({ height: '0px' });

                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');

                open = false;

            }

        });     

    });


            jQuery(function($) {

        var open = false;

        $('#footerSlideButton3').click(function () {

            if(open === false) {

                $('#footerSlideContent3').animate({ height: '300px' });

                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');

                open = true;

            } else {

                $('#footerSlideContent3').animate({ height: '0px' });

                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');

                open = false;

            }

        });     

    });
```

Here is my html with the div I'm referring to:

```
<div id="footerSlideContainer">
    <div id="footerSlideButton"></div>
    <div id="footerSlideContent">
        <div id="footerSlideText">
            <h3>Online Brochures</h3>
            <p>Coming Soon!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this: `<a href="JavaScript:popuptabs.click('footerSlideButton');"></a>` in my div with no avail. I'm not sure what the correct way to call this function.

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying your sample code and giving more details on what actually happens.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: The code works fine when I embed it in the html page. However, I want to call the click function externally...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just give the link you want to call the function from an `id` value:

```
<a id="someLinkId" href="#">Link Text.</a>
```

and say:

```
$("#someLinkId").click(function () {
    $('#footerSlideButton').trigger('click');
});
```